# Render Django view in new window

Tags: python, django

I have a Django view that I want to render in a new window when it is called from a python script outside of views.py.  My questions are 1.Can I use a Django view from a python script in a subdirectory of my project that is outside the app where the view is located (view location: MyProject/Myapp/views.py and the python script location: MyProject/ProcessingCode/myscript.py)? 2. If that is possible, how do I render the view in a new window?

Django view that I want rendered in a new window:

```
def Error_Popup_Page(request,message):

  context = {'message':message}
  return render(request,'InterfaceApp/Error_Notification.html',context)
```

How it will be used:

```
def SomeOtherPythonFunction():
  try:
    #data processing code
  except Exception as e:
    return Error_Popup_Page(request,'error message')
```

Comment: do you have access to request object in your python script?

Comment: but honestly, I dont understand how a python script should be opening a new window if the script is not interested in httprequest

Comment: This is a terribly bad architecture. I highly recommend that you import your Python script into your views.py.

Told that, django views are just functions that take a request object and output a web response.

What do you mean "new window"? A new browser window? What action from the user should trigger the opening of this window? Who is supposed to call that Python script?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there's no way you can open a new window in a browser from the server side. You'd have to do that via an anchor tag or JavaScript.

Comment: @Saturnix I need a way to show the user via the website if an error occurs while I'm processing data in my python script (in the background).  So if an error is detected I want to be able to have a new browser window pop up displaying the error.  I can't import the python code into my views.py because it is really a module with 2000 lines of code in it.

Comment: 1) This is impossible to do neither with Django nor with an external Python script. You need to use a websocket or a timer on the user end and an async task queue like Celery (which can be integrated into Django)

2) It doesn't matter how long a script is, using an import statement in Python and you'll have access to all of its class and functions.

I'm sorry but there is no way to trigger any event on the user browser starting from the server, unless there is a websocket listening. All the events are triggered FROM the browser TO your server, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to trigger a change on the user browser from on an event that happens on your server. This is impossible to do with Django alone, since Django job is only to respond user requests.

This is where Django is placed in the request chain:

> User browser (click on href or ajax event) --> Your server --> Django
>   --> User browser (gets response and display to the user)

As you can see, there is no way for Django to trigger any event on the user end without the user calling it.

What you're trying to do can be achieved with an async task: in other words, you have to open a [websocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications) and connect the user browser to it with JavaScript.

There are many frameworks for doing this, [Celery](https://realpython.com/blog/python/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/) being the most used in conjuction with Django.

[nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) is also widely used but integrating it with Django is more complex.